# While using a custom flow layout the click events are not being propagated on all devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a custom layout to display a varied number of buttons and intercept their clicks. Here is the source code for the custom layout:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class FlowLayout extends AdapterView<Adapter> {
    public static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
    public static final int VERTICAL = 1;
    private static final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_RESTING = 0;
    private static final int TOUCH_STATE_CLICK = 1;
    private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_RESTING;
    private Rect mRect;
    private Runnable mLongPressRunnable;
    private int mTouchStartX;
    private int mTouchStartY;
    private int horizontalSpacing = 0;
    private int verticalSpacing = 0;
    private int orientation = 0;
    private boolean debugDraw = false;
    private Adapter mAdapter;
    private final AdapterObserver mObserver = new AdapterObserver();

    public FlowLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.readStyleParameters(context, null);
    }

    public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        this.readStyleParameters(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);

        this.readStyleParameters(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int sizeWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - this.getPaddingRight() - this.getPaddingLeft();
        int sizeHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - this.getPaddingRight() - this.getPaddingLeft();

        int modeWidth = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int modeHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        int size;
        int mode;

        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            size = sizeWidth;
            mode = modeWidth;
        } else {
            size = sizeHeight;
            mode = modeHeight;
        }

        int lineThicknessWithSpacing = 0;
        int lineThickness = 0;
        int lineLengthWithSpacing = 0;
        int lineLength;

        int prevLinePosition = 0;

        int controlMaxLength = 0;
        int controlMaxThickness = 0;

        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == GONE) {
                continue;
            }

            child.measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeWidth, modeWidth == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : modeWidth),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(sizeHeight, modeHeight == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.AT_MOST : modeHeight)
            );

            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int hSpacing = this.getHorizontalSpacing(lp);
            int vSpacing = this.getVerticalSpacing(lp);

            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();

            int childLength;
            int childThickness;
            int spacingLength;
            int spacingThickness;

            if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                childLength = childWidth;
                childThickness = childHeight;
                spacingLength = hSpacing;
                spacingThickness = vSpacing;
            } else {
                childLength = childHeight;
                childThickness = childWidth;
                spacingLength = vSpacing;
                spacingThickness = hSpacing;
            }

            lineLength = lineLengthWithSpacing + childLength;
            lineLengthWithSpacing = lineLength + spacingLength;

            boolean newLine = lp.newLine || (mode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && lineLength > size);
            if (newLine) {
                prevLinePosition = prevLinePosition + lineThicknessWithSpacing;

                lineThickness = childThickness;
                lineLength = childLength;
                lineThicknessWithSpacing = childThickness + spacingThickness;
                lineLengthWithSpacing = lineLength + spacingLength;
            }

            lineThicknessWithSpacing = Math.max(lineThicknessWithSpacing, childThickness + spacingThickness);
            lineThickness = Math.max(lineThickness, childThickness);

            int posX;
            int posY;
            if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                posX = getPaddingLeft() + lineLength - childLength;
                posY = getPaddingTop() + prevLinePosition;
            } else {
                posX = getPaddingLeft() + prevLinePosition;
                posY = getPaddingTop() + lineLength - childHeight;
            }
            lp.setPosition(posX, posY);

            controlMaxLength = Math.max(controlMaxLength, lineLength);
            controlMaxThickness = prevLinePosition + lineThickness;
        }

        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            this.setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(controlMaxLength, widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(controlMaxThickness, heightMeasureSpec));
        } else {
            this.setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(controlMaxThickness, widthMeasureSpec), resolveSize(controlMaxLength, heightMeasureSpec));
        }
    }

    private int getVerticalSpacing(LayoutParams lp) {
        int vSpacing;
        if (lp.verticalSpacingSpecified()) {
            vSpacing = lp.verticalSpacing;
        } else {
            vSpacing = this.verticalSpacing;
        }
        return vSpacing;
    }

    private int getHorizontalSpacing(LayoutParams lp) {
        int hSpacing;
        if (lp.horizontalSpacingSpecified()) {
            hSpacing = lp.horizontalSpacing;
        } else {
            hSpacing = this.horizontalSpacing;
        }
        return hSpacing;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), lp.y + child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        boolean more = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
        this.drawDebugInfo(canvas, child);
        return more;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return p instanceof LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return new LayoutParams(p);
    }

    private void readStyleParameters(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.FlowLayout);
        try {
            horizontalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_horizontalSpacing, 0);
            verticalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_verticalSpacing, 0);
            orientation = a.getInteger(R.styleable.FlowLayout_orientation, HORIZONTAL);
            debugDraw = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.FlowLayout_debugDraw, false);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void drawDebugInfo(Canvas canvas, View child) {
        if (!debugDraw) {
            return;
        }

        Paint childPaint = this.createPaint(0xffffff00);
        Paint layoutPaint = this.createPaint(0xff00ff00);
        Paint newLinePaint = this.createPaint(0xffff0000);

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        if (lp.horizontalSpacing > 0) {
            float x = child.getRight();
            float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y, childPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + lp.horizontalSpacing - 4.0f, y - 4.0f, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y, childPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + lp.horizontalSpacing - 4.0f, y + 4.0f, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y, childPaint);
        } else if (this.horizontalSpacing > 0) {
            float x = child.getRight();
            float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + this.horizontalSpacing, y, layoutPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + this.horizontalSpacing - 4.0f, y - 4.0f, x + this.horizontalSpacing, y, layoutPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + this.horizontalSpacing - 4.0f, y + 4.0f, x + this.horizontalSpacing, y, layoutPaint);
        }

        if (lp.verticalSpacing > 0) {
            float x = child.getLeft() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            float y = child.getBottom();
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y + lp.verticalSpacing, childPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x - 4.0f, y + lp.verticalSpacing - 4.0f, x, y + lp.verticalSpacing, childPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + 4.0f, y + lp.verticalSpacing - 4.0f, x, y + lp.verticalSpacing, childPaint);
        } else if (this.verticalSpacing > 0) {
            float x = child.getLeft() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            float y = child.getBottom();
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y + this.verticalSpacing, layoutPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x - 4.0f, y + this.verticalSpacing - 4.0f, x, y + this.verticalSpacing, layoutPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + 4.0f, y + this.verticalSpacing - 4.0f, x, y + this.verticalSpacing, layoutPaint);
        }

        if (lp.newLine) {
            if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
                float x = child.getLeft();
                float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
                canvas.drawLine(x, y - 6.0f, x, y + 6.0f, newLinePaint);
            } else {
                float x = child.getLeft() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f;
                float y = child.getTop();
                canvas.drawLine(x - 6.0f, y, x + 6.0f, y, newLinePaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private Paint createPaint(int color) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
        return paint;
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {
        private static int NO_SPACING = -1;

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int horizontalSpacing = NO_SPACING;
        private int verticalSpacing = NO_SPACING;
        private boolean newLine = false;

        public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
            super(context, attributeSet);
            this.readStyleParameters(context, attributeSet);
        }

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams) {
            super(layoutParams);
        }

        public boolean horizontalSpacingSpecified() {
            return horizontalSpacing != NO_SPACING;
        }

        public boolean verticalSpacingSpecified() {
            return verticalSpacing != NO_SPACING;
        }

        public void setHorizontalSpacing(int hs) {
            horizontalSpacing = hs;
        }

        public void setVerticalSpacing(int vs) {
            verticalSpacing = vs;
        }

        public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        private void readStyleParameters(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams);
            try {
                horizontalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_horizontalSpacing, NO_SPACING);
                verticalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_verticalSpacing, NO_SPACING);
                newLine = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_newLine, false);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);

        refresh();
    }


    public void refresh() {
        removeAllViewsInLayout();        
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            final View view = mAdapter.getView(i, null, this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            if (params == null) {
                params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
            addViewInLayout(view, i, params, true);
        }
        postInvalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public class AdapterObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    // Touch detection
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
        if (getChildCount() == 0) { 
            return false; 
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                startTouch(event); 
                break; 

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) { 
                    clickChildAt((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()); 
                } 
                endTouch(); 
                break; 

            default: 
                endTouch(); 
                break; 
        } 

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets and initializes all things that need to when we start a touch
     * gesture.
     * 
     * @param event The down event
     */
    private void startTouch(final MotionEvent event) {
        mTouchStartX = (int)event.getX();
        mTouchStartY = (int)event.getY();
        startLongPressCheck();

        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_CLICK;
    }

    private void startLongPressCheck() {
        if (mLongPressRunnable == null) {
            mLongPressRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) {
                        final int index = getContainingChildIndex(mTouchStartX, mTouchStartY);
                        if (index != INVALID_INDEX) { longClickChild(index); mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_RESTING; }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        postDelayed(mLongPressRunnable, 300); //ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout()
    }

    private void longClickChild(final int index) {
        final View itemView = getChildAt(index);
        final int position = index;
        final long id = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        final OnItemLongClickListener listener = getOnItemLongClickListener();
        if (listener != null) { listener.onItemLongClick(this, itemView, position, id); }
    }

    private int getContainingChildIndex(final int x, final int y) {
        if (mRect == null) { mRect = new Rect(); }
        for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
            getChildAt(index).getHitRect(mRect);
            if (mRect.contains(x, y)) { return index; }
        }
        return INVALID_INDEX;
    }

    private void endTouch() {
        removeCallbacks(mLongPressRunnable);
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_RESTING;
    }

    private void clickChildAt(final int x, final int y) {
        final int index = getContainingChildIndex(x, y);
        if (index != INVALID_INDEX) {
            final View itemView = getChildAt(index);
            final int position = index;
            final long id = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
            performItemClick(itemView, position, id);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works on my test device which is a Google Nexus S with Android 4.1.2, meaning that the buttons are clickable. Yet I got reports that the buttons are unresponsive on other devices such as Android Casio C771 with Android version 2.3.3 and Verizon LG VS840 with Android 4.0.4.

Can you please tell me what could cause this discrepancy and how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to log calls to onTouchEvenet on these phones to see if it is being called at all, and if so what it coming in?

Comment: I tried logging calls but those events don't fire at all. Unfortunately I don't have easy access to the phones on which it doesn't work (ie. Casio C771, Verizon LG VS840)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to look out for:

1. It is essential that the `View`s created for the adapter are enabled for click and touch action. After they are created:

   ```
   View.setEnabled(true);
   ```
2. When you create the `AdapterView` and the `BaseApapter`, remember to both `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemLongClickListener` if you want to handle long clicks, which it seems you do.
3. In the `endTouch` routine, you need to set `mLongPressRunnable` to null, so it will be created for the next touch (or lose the `null` check in `startLongPressCheck` and handle concurency issues another way).
4. The runnable created in `startLongPressCheck` needs to call `endTouch` when complete to reset everything to the right, nothing pending, state after the long press time period.
5. In the `onTouchEvent` `switch` statement, it is important to not call your `endTouch` routine, because this means that movement events may stop the click.
6. There is a suggestion (see [Android onClick method doesn't work on a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703548/android-onclick-method-doesnt-work-on-a-custom-view)) that if you don't call `super.onTouchEvent(event)` in your `onTouchEvent` it can cause problems. This would look something like:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
       if (getChildCount() == 0) { 
           return super.onTouchEvent(event); 
       }

       boolean handled = false;

       switch (event.getAction()) { 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
               startTouch(event); 
               handled = true;
               break;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
               if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) { 
                   clickChildAt((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                   handled = true;
               } 
               endTouch();
           break; 

           default: 
               // Do not do anything dramatic here because the system
               // may send different (eg. motion) information here which
               // may lead to you losing valid clicks if you simply cancel
               // the click in process.
           break;
       } 

   if (handled == false) handled = super.onTouchEvent(event);

   return handled;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I will try it out. Unfortunately I only have a device on which my original code works already and I don't have access to one where that doesn't, so it would be difficult to test to see if this is the correct solution. Do you happen to have any non Google Nexus S with Android 4.1.2 device where this could be tested on?

Comment: I tried your code and the good news is that it works. Unfortunately I still can't tell if it does on any other device. Please let me know if you can test on others.

Comment: I created a sample project that uses this layout and your solution. It works on my phone. Please check that it works on yours. Here is the zipfile. It has all source code. http://ge.tt/94REsAi/v/0?c Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your help. Did it not work initially and now it works? Ideally I would like it to work for long press also. Would it be possible to get the working code ?

Comment: Code which works on 4.0.3 now but didn't initially: http://ge.tt/2Fh44Gi/v/0 (best guess at key change: adding int `setEnabled()` to the adapter.

Comment: I just tested your code. It works great! Thanks for your help.