# Set onClickListener in an Android custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button, android-library

I am trying build simple library for button,
inside library folder  I created below class

```
 public class SimpleImageButton extends AppCompatImageView implements AppCompatImageView.OnClickListener{

    public Context mContext;
    Activity activity;

    public SimpleImageButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setCustomTypeface(context, null);

    }

    public SimpleImageButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setCustomTypeface(context, attrs);

    }

    public SimpleImageButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;
        setCustomTypeface(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setCustomTypeface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        if(isInEditMode())
            return;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
        android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.TextAppearance);
        setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, 
    R.drawable.applogo_ads));
        a.recycle();

    }
   public void onClick(View view) {
        // here i have some functions to execute
    }
}
```

and my Mainclass in App folder

```
   SimpleImageButton imgBtn= (SimpleImageButton )findViewById(R.id.clickButton);

imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               imgBtn.onClick(view);
              // without this line how can i reach to onclick() of simpleImageButton class
            }
        });
```

so it is woking fine when i click button. but i want to make library button to work directly, without onClick function inside main activity, on clicking button should directly redirect to SimpleImageButton class onclcik method

I am very new to stack overflow , if any mistakes in the grammar / way of asking question please never mind.
thank you.

Comment: Use Call back listener in your library .. onClick of listener just send call back to parent activity or fragment

Comment: i want to acheive something like i should not write anything in main activity for click action !!!!!! onclicking that button it shoud directly perform function that is present inside SimpleImageButton class onclick() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setOnClickListener(this) inside your view's constructor.

```java
public SimpleImageButton (Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setCustomTypeface(context, null);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Furthermore, you still need to be able to set  the click listener in the consumer. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733216/294884

Answer (score 1):

I just override the this **dispatchTouchEvent** and **dispatchKeyEvent** and
create own public function **setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener)** to set on click listener

```
public class SimpleImageButton extends AppCompatImageView{
        //...
         private OnClickListener listener;
        
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (listener != null) listener.onClick(this);
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            }
        
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    if (listener != null) listener.onClick(this);
                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
            public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
               this.listener = listener;
            }
    }
```

Now I hope it will be clickable just like other buttons.