# Material Spinner (AutoCompleteTextView) - catch outside clicks

Tags: android, material-components-android

When using a spinner, it's the default behaviour that clicks outside of the spinner close the spinner but are NOT handled by the view underneath the click.

When switching to `TextInputLayout` + `AutoCompleteTextView` this behaviour is different, clicking on something outside the "spinner" closes the spinner AND the view underneath the touch does get the click event as well - this is very annoying and imho unexpected.

Can I somehow disable this behaviour to get the same behaviour as I get when using an old spinner?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no chances to catch the touch outside event using `setOnDismissListener` or `dismissDropDown()`; the latter gets called when item is selected.

But that would be possible by registering `OnDismissListener` on the instance of the inner popup window of the `AutoCompleteTextView` which is of type `ListPopupWindow` through reflections:

```
private fun getPopup(): ListPopupWindow? {
    try {
        val field = AutoCompleteTextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
        field.isAccessible = true
        return field.get(this) as ListPopupWindow
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Hopefully, the documentation can solve this to avoid this anti-pattern.

The `OnDismissListener` callback gets called on any type of dismissal of the menu; either clicking on items, touching outside the `AutoCompleteTextView` or hitting the soft keyboard back button. This can be distinguished by tagging the `ACTT` with the appropriate flag for each event; an `enum` is used for that in the below customized class):

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.ListPopupWindow
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView

class TouchOutsideAutoCompleteTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView(context, attrs), AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    init {

        super.setOnItemClickListener(this)

        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    viewTreeObserver
                        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                else
                    viewTreeObserver
                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)

                // Registering the mPopup window OnDismissListener
                adjustTouchOutside()
            }

        })

    }

    private var consumerListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null

    private enum class DismissEvent {
        ON_ITEM_CLICK, // Should be set to enable the next touch dispatch event whenever the dismiss is due to a click on the menu item.
        ON_TOUCH_OUTSIDE, // Should be set to disable the next touch dispatch event whenever the dismiss is due to a touch outside the menu.
        ON_BACK_PRESSED // Should be set to enable the next touch dispatch event whenever the dismiss is due to the software keyboard back button pressed.
    }

    /*
    * Called globally on any touch on the screen to consume the event if it returns true
    * */
    fun isDismissByTouchOutside() = tag == DismissEvent.ON_TOUCH_OUTSIDE

    private fun isDismissByItemClickOrBackPressed() =
        tag == DismissEvent.ON_ITEM_CLICK || tag == DismissEvent.ON_BACK_PRESSED

    private fun setDismissToItemClick() {
        tag = DismissEvent.ON_ITEM_CLICK
    }

    private fun setDismissToTouchOutside() {
        tag = DismissEvent.ON_TOUCH_OUTSIDE
    }

    private fun setDismissToBackPressed() {
        tag = DismissEvent.ON_BACK_PRESSED
    }


    fun clearDismissEvent() {
        tag = null
    }

    @SuppressLint("DiscouragedPrivateApi")
    private fun getPopup(): ListPopupWindow? {
        try {
            val field = AutoCompleteTextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
            field.isAccessible = true
            return field.get(this) as ListPopupWindow
        } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun adjustTouchOutside() {
        getPopup()?.let {
            it.setOnDismissListener {
                if (isDismissByItemClickOrBackPressed()) {// Menu dismissal Event of clicking on the menu item or hitting the software back button
                    clearDismissEvent() // Neutralize the enum to allow the next touch dispatch event & for adding a chance of next dismissal decision

                } else {  // Menu dismissal Event of touching outside the menu
                    // Don't allow the next touch dispatch event
                    setDismissToTouchOutside()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        setDismissToItemClick()
        consumerListener?.onItemClick(p0, p1, p2, p3)
    }

    override fun setOnItemClickListener(l: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener?) {
        // DO NOT CALL SUPER HERE
//        super.setOnItemClickListener(l)
        consumerListener = l
    }

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing)
            setDismissToBackPressed()
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }

}
```

**The usage**

Overriding `dispatchTouchEvent()` in the activity is required to consume the event for touching outside by checking `isTouchOutsideDisabled()`; and neutralize the dismissal event:

If the `AutoCompleteTextView` is in the activity then:

```
lateinit var autoCTV: TouchOutsideAutoCompleteTextView

override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (autoCTV.isDismissByTouchOutside()) {
        autoCTV.clearDismissEvent()
        return true
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

If it is in some fragment, then the `dispatchTouchEvent()` need to have access to it:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MyFragmentTag") as MyFragment

    if (fragment.autoCTV.isDismissByTouchOutside()) {
        fragment.autoCTV.clearDismissEvent()
        return true
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Comment: Reflection + manual code adjustments... Really ugly, but a working solution... I would handle the `enableTouchOutside` and `adjustTouchoutside` functions inside the custom class only though - I think that's possible with some custom wrapper for the click listener... If nothing better is suggested, I may really go this route for now... I will at least open a github issue in the material components repo as well. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @prom85 thanks for the comment. Totally agree; this has been refined by moving the `enableTouchOutside` and `adjustTouchoutside` functions inside the custom view; thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733216/9851608) for the `onItemClickListener` part. Regarding the reflection; hopefully Google can offer some API publicly to developers. Pls have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: A couple of recently noticed things, registering the menu listeners in `onPreDraw()` is not good as it will be recalled when the menu pops up or pops off. So, a global listener is created in the `init` method. Second, if you dismiss the menu with the soft keyboard button, then the next touch event will be dropped; this is fixed by registering `onKeyPreIme` in the updated answer.

Comment: Answer is ok as there seems to be no better solution... Regarding `dispatchTouchEvent` - you mean you use a custom root view inside our fragment/activity which handles this and manages the `autoCTV` correct?

Comment: I used `dispatchTouchEvent()` in activity; it intercepts any touch event on the screen before dispatching that to the target view; for fragments there is no such method; one possible solution to register a listener between the fragment and activity to send the ACTV status; or you could have an access to the fragment from the activity to get the ACTV instance directly in the activity & normally register `dispatchTouchEvent`. There could be better solutions in the fragment let me check it out

Comment: Tried to registering onTouchListener for the fragment's root view when the ACTV is in a fragment; it works; but the problem that if you lay other views on the fragment; and the user dismisses the ACTV menu by hitting any of these views; it won't work unless you repeat the same for all those potential views that the user can hit; otherwise you can access the ACTV from the activity (updated the answer with that) and continue using `dispatchTouchEvent()`