# how to get click position in onClickListener?

Tags: java, android

How to get click position with onClickListener? Like follow in onTouchListener.

```
      int x = (int)event.getX();
      int y = (int)event.getY();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967039/onclicklistener-x-y-location-of-event

Comment: the mods are goofy, "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here". Are they so dumb? I can instantly understand the question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an onTouchListener with ACTION_DOWN flag

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The behavior from this is far from onClickListener. A `Floating Action Button` (for instance) click event is very different from a touch down event.

Comment: Click is a combination of an `ACTION_DOWN` with `ACTION_UP` within a certain amount of time and without moving "a lot". So this doesn't answer the question.