# How can I scroll item to middle of screen in scrollView when I press them

Tags: android, scrollview

My project need to insert lots of data,I use scrollview to put them in one page.

Now I want it can scroll the item I press(primary Edittext) to the middle of screen.

I tried to use onFocusChangeListener()+scrollTo() with edittexts,but doesn't work very well.

Is there any better way to do it?

[image: I want to make it act like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have an `onTouchListener` for the `scrollview`.

When the user touches the screen, grab the x and y coordinates and then simply scroll to that point. So `scrollview.scrollTo(x,y)`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967039/onclicklistener-x-y-location-of-event) for more info

Comment: I had just tried it but doesn't work very well.....

It didn't make my edittext in the middle of the screen and I can't scroll it myself anymore.....

This is what I just add:



   `scrollViewPage1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

         @Override

         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if (event.getAction() ==     MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
              scrollViewPage1.scrollTo((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
             }
             return true;
         }

   
     });`

Comment: Try using a `onClickListener` that way you can still scroll ontouch