# Onclick on an specific "square" of canvas view

Tags: android, canvas, touch, listener

I have a board with dices painted on it, drawn with canvas. I have about 3 or 4 buttons drawn too on it with different variables for specific bitmap. I know how to put a clickListener on the whole canvas view but i'd like to put specific function attached to specific button designed on the canvas view but i don't know how

Comment: can you add to your question, the relevant code you have so far?

Comment: nvm,  this has been (sort of) asked before here, Use a touchlistener to trap the x & y locations http://stackoverflow.com/a/4023317/794088

Comment: But coordinates depends on phone size and pixeles density, how to do it properly?

Comment: "how to do it properly", hard to say w/o seeing any code

Comment: I have 3 classes with lots of functions to draw it and do lot of things about canvas, its hard to put all code and I don't even know how to put the <html > or something like that